# How to stop Symfony from logging Doctrine's sql queries?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a weird issue, when I checked my `app/log/dev.log` I can see almost all of my queries in my `dev.log` being logged in real time:

```
[2015-01-27 06:57:22] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username A ....
[2015-01-27 06:57:23] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username A ...
[2015-01-27 06:57:23] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT s0_.id ......
```

I have no idea why this is happening, since I am running the site on production mode also when I check monolog in my `config.yml`, this is what I see:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        pictures:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/pictures_%kernel.environment%.log
            level: info
        instagram:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/instagram_%kernel.environment%.log
            level: info
```

here's what my config_dev.yml looks like:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: false

hip_mandrill:
    disable_delivery: true
```

any idea how this could be happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `prod` env on your production server. In the `prod` env doctrine's logging is disabled by default.

But if you want to disable logging at all (in all environments) you need to set up a `config.yml` like that:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            conn1:
                driver: ...
                ...
                logging: false
                profiling: false
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html

Comment: I think I am using the prod env on my production server.. I don't want to disable all loggings, just in the prod. If not how can I check that this is the case

Comment: In `prod` env you will have logs at `app/logs/prod.log`

Comment: I understand that, however no one seems to be accessing the dev environment, yet the logs are always going there.. I am afraid the prod environment is not really using the prod flag...so how do I check it

Comment: As I wrote before. You are actually using `prod` env. You can rename or delete your `config_dev.yml` and your application will not work. To activate `prod` env you need to point your web-server to use `app.php` instead of `app_dev.php`

Comment: I also have another environment, a custom one called app_mobile, but how do I make sure that this is production and not development

Comment: I don't believe you:-) Post your `.htaccess` here and your `app.php`

Comment: In your front controller (app.php or app_mobile.php) you instantiate `AppKernel` with two parameters: first argument is a name of your environment (e.g. `prod`) and the second is debug flag (if true debug-mode will be enabled). The name then is used in filepaths for logs and cache (`app/logs/your_env_name_here.log` and `app/cache/your_env_name_here/`)

Comment: If you want disable SQL logging only in one or any actions (not disable in global scope), you can rewrite/drop SQL Logger from Doctrine Configuration: `$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection')->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar issue with `dev.log` being generated on `prod` environment.  I figured out from the log entries that what was causing my issue was a scheduled cron job calling a custom symfony command. Modifying the entry to `app/console` with `--env=prod` for my crontab since stopped `dev.log` being generated. i.e.

```
app/console --env=prod custom:command
```

Must have missed that section of the book :)

Comment: Thank you! I discovered my log was 1.7 GB when I found this solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I struggled with the same problem and my .log file was increasing its size the straight solution was when running the consumer use the flag --no-debug

```
php bin/console messenger:consume async_email_handler --no-debug
```