# Doctrine MongoDB disable logger on fixture load

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

Is there a way to disable Doctrine MongoDB bundle logger on fixture load only? like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35222045/3965970 but for MongoDB bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely the same way, call 
`$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setLoggerCallable(null);` right in the fixture.

Comment: I tried to use `setLoggerCallable(null)` method call before. It does not remove exists logger.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Doctrine MongoODM-bundle version 4.0 and higher this approach no longer works.

The easiest way is to disable logging in the configuration, see https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html

You can also disable the logger manually, but you'll need `doctrine_mongodb.odm.command_logger` service.

What I did in my Symfony 4 application is to create an alias to enable proper dependency injection and then unregister the listener:

services.yaml

```
Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\APM\PSRCommandLogger:
    alias: "doctrine_mongodb.odm.command_logger"
```

some constructor of a Command or Service:

```php
public function __construct(PSRCommandLogger $mongoLogger)
{
    $mongoLogger->unregister();
}
```