# Doctrine 2: memory leak when removing and flushing entity in preflush event

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `X` which contains a collection of `Y` entities. The `Y` entities are "privately owned" by entity `X`, which means that when an `Y` entity is removed from the collection, it should be completely removed from the database.

Normally, this can be achieved using `orphanRemoval`, but because of the standard flushing order (collection inserts before collection updates before collection deletions), a unique constraint on the `Y` entity is destined to fail if a new or updated item has the same values as a deleted item.

To tackle this issue, I manually keep track of removed `Y` entities from the collection by storing them in a separate array (without using `orphanRemoval`):

```
public function removeY(Y $y) : X
{
    $y->setX(null);
    $this->removedYItems[] = $y;
    $this->yCollection->removeElement($y);
    return $this;
}
```

When a `flush` operation is called, I manually commit the removed items in a `preFlush` event:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreFlush
 */
public function onPreFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $eventArgs) : void
{
    if (count($this->removedYItems) === 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($this->removedYItems as $removedYItem)
    {
        $entityManager->remove($removedYItem);
    }

    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

At the end I explicitly call `flush` to ensure the items are removed from the database before any updates or insertions.

However, after calling the flush operation the web page seems to hang and when I look at my server logs, PHP seems to have run out of memory (1GiB):

```
[Sat Nov 25 00:32:14.016294 2017] [php7:error] [pid 22212] [client 192.168.0.1:59174] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Is this a (known) Doctrine bug causing a memory leak? Or am I not supposed to call `flush` in a `preFlush` event (the documentation says otherwise: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preflush)?

I am running PHP 7.1.11 on FreeBSD 11.0 STABLE with Doctrine 2.5.9. I'll try to test this on another machine as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests, it seems the `preFlush` event is stuck in an infinite recursive loop (as hinted by @geolim4). I created an issue in the Doctrine repository on GitHub asking for clarification, and they told me this is a mistake in the documentation: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6857.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with profiler enabled, turn it off for Doctrine.
See how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28192241/2123869).
Sf Profiler is known to be very memory-greedy when working with a bunch of entities.

Comment: The problem is that this happens even with only 1 scheduled entity before the flush: https://pastebin.com/raw/d9YCK11L. Even with logging enabled, nothing is logged and the memory keeps spiraling out of control.

Comment: Ahh I think I get it. You got an infinite recursive call.
onPreFlush() is calling $entityManager->flush() which is calling onPreFlush() event etc..

Comment: That might be the case indeed. However, the documentation explicitly mentions it is safe to call `flush` inside `preflush` (see link in my original question). Maybe this is a bug or an error in the documentation?

Comment: I'll try to add some kind of logging to the beginning of the `preFlush` event to see if it gets called multiple times (`var_dump` or Symfony's `dump` won't work because the request never finishes).